# Sftp "subsystem request failed on channel 0" error

Tags: sftp

I'm trying to sftp files from a remote server running Ubuntu 20.04.3 (server 1), to another remote server (server 2), using a Nodejs library called "ssh2".  I was getting errors in my node app about "Couldn't start subsystem sftp", so I tried calling sftp directly from the command line on server 1:

```
sftp -b /path/to/local/file -i /my/rsa_file user@server2.com:/path/to/ship/file -v
```

and got:

```
subsystem request failed on channel 0
Connection closed
```

I'm not a server admin by any stretch, but I'm guessing that Ubuntu isn't configured for outgoing sftp by default.  How can I configure things to get this working?  I'd also like to run the production code running on server 1 on my local machine (macbook), so I'd like to get this working there as well.

Troubleshooting steps so far:

- Tried ssh from server 1 to server 2 and it works fine
- On server 1, checked /etc/ssh/sshd_config and found the following line: `Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`
- Then checked for /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server and file exists
- That's it.  I'm lost.

Comment: That message looks like it comes from the server side not the client side - it would be the *destination* server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that you would need to check

Comment: @steeldriver I hadn't considered that, but just did the same troubleshooting steps on the destination server and found the same results there

Comment: Hmm... I just noticed you are using the `-b` (batch mode) option, but also specifying a remote file - are you sure that's appropriate? Does the connection succeed in simple interactive mode ex. `sftp -i /my/rsa_file user@server2.com` ?

Comment: I'd suggest upgrading your system asap, esp. if it's online. Your provided details imply you've not apply security fixes/upgrades since Jan 2022?  as https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/ will show when 20.04.4 ISO was released for new installs, but installed systems upgrade well before then. Your system should currently state 20.04.4 but already be running most of 20.04.5 upgrades (*having already been rolling out; version change being the last of the changes*).  Your lack of upgrades may also show a package problem; thus be related too....

Answer (score 0):

First check the line of Subsystem sftp setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Then check if the executable mentioned above exists. For me it is located under: `/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server`
If it doesn't exists try reinstalling sftp-server from your package manager or find the appropriate executable file (using `which` and `whereis`) and copy it there or simply change the config file to the correct location.
Finally make sure it has the correct permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 63K Aug 27 12:07 /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Don't forget to restart ssh service using `sudo systemctl restart ssh` on systemd distros or `sudo service ssh restart` otherwise.